# Easier way to find the average of a set of numbers in Python

Tags: python, average

I need an easier way to find the average of a set of numbers using Python. My code is long and tedious and I do not want to expend more effort adding `elif` statements above 5:

```
aom = input("How many numbers would you like to average?")

if str(aom) == '1':
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    listt = [num]
    total = num
    nums = (num)
elif str(aom) == '2':
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    num1 = input("Enter a number:")
    listt = [num,num1]
    total = (int(num) + int(num1))
    nums = [num, num1]
elif str(aom) == '3':
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    num1 = input("Enter a number:")
    num2 = input("Enter a number:")
    listt = [num,num1,num2]
    total =(int(num) + int(num1) + int(num2))
    num = [num, num1, num2]
elif str(aom) == '4':
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    num1 = input("Enter a number:")
    num2 = input("Enter a number:")
    num3 = input("Enter a number:")
    listt = [num,num1,num2,num3]
    total = (int(num) + int(num1) + int(num2) + int(num3))
    nums = [num, num1, num2, num3]
elif str(aom) == '5':
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    num1 = input("Enter a number:")
    num2 = input("Enter a number:")
    num3 = input("Enter a number:")
    num4 = input("Enter a number:")
    listt = [num,num,num,num,num]
    total = (int(num) + int(num1) + int(num2) + int(num3) + int(num4))
    nums = [num, num1, num2, num3, num4]
else:
    print("Sorry, please pick 1-5")
    exit()
size = len(listt)
average = (int(total)/int(size))
print("The numbers given were", nums)
print("The average is", average)
```

This is a coding problem for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a loop:

```
answers = int(input("How many numbers would you like to average? "))

numbers = []

for answer in range(1, answers + 1):
    number = int(input("Enter number {}: ".format(answer)))
    numbers.append(number)

average = sum(numbers) / answers
print("The numbers given were:", numbers)
print("The average is:", average)
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
> python3 test.py
How many numbers would you like to average? 3
Enter number 1: 10
Enter number 2: 13
Enter number 3: 19
The numbers given were: [10, 13, 19]
The average is: 14.0
>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you rewrite your script to collect all the numbers into a list you can pass that list to the sum() function to get the total.  then just divide that total by the length of the list.

```
average=sum(listofnumbers)/len(listofnumbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a general way to implement your function.

```
aom = int(input("How many numbers would you like to average?: "))
x = [int(input('{}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(aom) ]
print(sum(x)/ aom )
```

1. Setup the number of elements.
2. Read it in a list through a loop.
3. Sum up all the elements, and calculate the average.

---

If `list` is hard to comprehend at this moment. then you can also use a while loop.

```
aom = int(input("How many numbers would you like to average?: "))
i = 1
sumx = 0
while i <= aom:
    sumx +=int(input('{}: '.format(i)))
    i += 1 

print(sumx/ aom )
```

Comment: I think list comprehension tricks are quite hard to understand for newbies.